# Setting a random seed outside vs inside a loop

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I am interested in generating a random number repeatedly when I run a loop in Python. So, I set a seed outside the loop. However, I get different random numbers for each iteration.

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(2)
for i in range(5):
    print(rng.random())
```

I get following output:

```
0.2616121342493164
0.2984911434141233
0.8142257405942803
0.0919159421350969
0.600100525965654
```

When I set the seed inside the loop as:

```
for i in range(5):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(2)
    print(rng.random())
```

I get the expected output:

```
0.2616121342493164
0.2616121342493164
0.2616121342493164
0.2616121342493164
0.2616121342493164
```

I thought (wrongly) that setting the seed at the top of my code would mean all the random numbers generated below that line would be same.  What am I missing?

Comment: Setting the seed *once* means that you have reproducible runs. If you run your programs multiple times, you'll see the same output. Having same random number on every iteration would defeat the randomness idea: you can just create a number outside of loop and then use it multiple times in a loop. There is no need in method that will make all further randomly generated numbers equal.